# Error when Deploy PHP to Azure Web App using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: php, jenkins

I'm stuck at the jenkins stage to deploy from github repo to azure web app.

```
stage('Deployment to Staging')
    {
        azureWebAppPublish appName: 'app1', 
        azureCredentialsId: 'cred1', 
        filePath: '', 
        publishType: 'file', 
        resourceGroup: 'rg1', 
        slotName: '', 
        sourceDirectory: ''
    }
```

and the result is :

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.azure.util.AzureBaseCredentials.serializeToTokenData()[B
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.appservice.util.AzureUtils.getToken(AzureUtils.java:24)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.appservice.util.AzureUtils.buildClient(AzureUtils.java:28)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.appservice.WebAppDeploymentRecorder.perform(WebAppDeploymentRecorder.java:168)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:69)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

what am i do wrong with this pipeline ? i'm already set the credential with azure service princial and already verified. really need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already found the solution. turns out need to downgrade the azure credential plugin.

```
before : 
jenkins version : 2.289.2
azure credential plugin version : 182.v3ccd4a755864
```

after :

```
jenkins version : 2.289.2
azure credential plugin version : 4.0.6
```

to download the plugin manually, i'm using [ClickMe](https://plugins.jenkins.io/)
and upload it to jenkins GUI.